# X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h: No such file or directory

Tags: xorg, compiling, programming, c++

I've tried to compile https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228674 under Ubuntu.

Unfortunately ending up with following error:

```
/tmp/find-cursor$ make
cc find-cursor.c -o find-cursor -lX11
find-cursor.c:19:39: fatal error: X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h>
                                       ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I've tried with following suspects:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev libxss-dev libxtst6-dbg libxext6-dbg libxss1-dbg
```

but still no luck in compiling. Here is snippet for your convenience:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
cd /tmp
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/Carpetsmoker/find-cursor
cd find-cursor
make
```

## Solved:

FTR: to compile above code I had to :
`sudo apt-get install libxcomposite-dev libxdamage-dev libxrender-dev` and add `-std=gnu99` flag to cc in Makefile

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whenever a compile fails with a missing file simply leverage the infrastructure to search for the missing ubuntu package

```
apt-file search   some_missing_file_goes_here   #  cmd 1    
apt-file search   X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h   #  cmd 1
```

which returns with

```
libxcomposite-dev: /usr/include/X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h
```

so solution is to install that missing package

```
sudo apt-get install libxcomposite-dev              #  cmd 2
```

this technique works across any missing file

---

On a fresh OS if you issue

```
apt-file search   X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h
```

it will fail with error

```
The program 'apt-file' is currently not installed. To run 'apt-file' please ask your administrator to install the package 'apt-file'
```

which just means you need to do a one time setup of the local search cache so just run

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file -y
sudo apt-file update
```

now re-issue the search shown above (cmd 1) then install package (cmd 2)

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.  I feel unblocked for future issues.

Answer (score 1):

On http://packages.ubuntu.com/ you can search for packages containing a file.

For `X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h` that finds `libxcomposite-dev`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libxcursor-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libxi-dev
```

That should do it!